# Swift Template Function

Tags: swift, api

I am wondering how I can potentially remove some duplicate methods in Swift 5.

```
func CreateProjectPossibleAccount(possibleAccount: ProjectPossibleAccount) -> Data {
        var dataToReturn: Data?
        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        do {
            var request = getUrlRequestFor(RequestType.post)
            request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(possibleAccount)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, err) in
                guard let data = data else {return}
                dataToReturn = data
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            }.resume()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.dispatchGroup.wait()
        return dataToReturn!
    }
    
    func CreateMaterialIssueItem(item: NewMaterialIssueItem) -> Data {
        var dataToReturn: Data?
        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        do {
            var request = getUrlRequestFor(RequestType.post)
            request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(item)
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            (data, response, err) in
                guard let data = data else {return}
                dataToReturn = data
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            }.resume()
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.dispatchGroup.wait()
        return dataToReturn!
    }
```

I have several functions like this where the only real difference is the custom type that I create. Is there a way to just name this function Post(item: T) and pass in all the unique types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics to avoid code duplication. In the following example I'm assuming that `ProjectPossibleAccount` and `NewMaterialIssueItem` implement the `Decodable` protocol and also that `RequestType` is a enum. The `dispatchGroup` could also become a param of the method.

```
func request<T: Encodable>(item: T, requestType: RequestType) -> Data {
    var dataToReturn: Data?
    self.dispatchGroup.enter()
    
    do {
        var request = getUrlRequestFor(requestType)
        request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(item)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            dataToReturn = data
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }.resume()
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
    self.dispatchGroup.wait()
    return dataToReturn!
}
```

and you can call the method like this:

```
let possibleAccount: ProjectPossibleAccount = ProjectPossibleAccount()
let data = request(item: possibleAccount, requestType: .post)
```

Another approach for the previous example ( and because it is a simple one) is simply specifying the `item` param data type as a `Encodable`, like this:

```
func request(item: Encodable, requestType: RequestType) -> Data
```

Comment: When I copy your code over here's the error I get. ```Type 'T.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols ```. This line of code is where I get the problem. ```request.httpBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(T)```

Comment: @austin_wilcox21 My bad, instead of `.encode(T)` it must be `.encode(item)`

Comment: Thanks a ton for that answer. That has nailed it. Will be really nice to refactor my program now and have it look significantly cleaner.